# For two clocks with $x$ hours difference, what fraction of a day would both clocks form acute angle?

Tags: probability

**1st assumption that I made**: I thought that you don't need to do a calculation for a whole day, but finding out the probability during one hour would be enough since each hour would have same proportion of satisfying the condition.

**A. So let's set one clock to 12:00, and other to 1:00, which makes 1 hour difference.**

1. For 12:00, the time period that make minute/hour hands acute angle should be $0 $ ~  $180/11$ and $540/11$ ~ $0$

(if we set $x$ as a single minute, it should be clear. $5.5x < 90$ for the first hand, $360-6x + 0.5x <90$ for the second hand.

2. For 1:00, the time period that make minute/hour hands acute angle should be $0 $ ~  $240/11$ and $600/11$ ~ $0$

So the overlapping time should be $0 $ ~  $180/11$ and $600/11$ ~ $0$ during one hour, making it $2/33$

**B. for $x=2,3,4,5,6$**

Should divide $x$ to $2$ cases

a. when time difference is within $3$ hours

b. more than $3$ hours

I did this because the proportion of each time gets quite different after $3$ hours

for $x = 2$, its quite same as part A, just to move $60/11$ from each hands, making the answer $1/22$

When it comes to $x = 3$, however, the total time that forms acute angle between 3:00 ~ 4:00 becomes $360/11$ (starts from 0, and ends at $x$ satisfying $6x - (90 + 0.5x) < 90$ which makes $x = 360/11$) when $x = 1$ or $2$ the time period was $300/11$

So the answer for each hour should be, $1/22$ for $3$ hours, $1/33$ for $4$ hours, $1/66$ for $5$ hours, and $0$ for $6$ hours.

I intentionally skipped other hours since all of them could be dealt with using symmetry.

I solved this problem with my 1st assumption, but not sure whether this assumption would be valid.

Do you think there is a better way, or legitimate way to approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe write "what fraction of a day" instead of "how much proportion of a day".

Comment: Just as a general rule, if you are not sure that an assumption is valid, then the assumption is not valid, whether it gives the correct answer or not. If it is not obvious (at the level of the audience you are trying to convince - even if that audience is just yourself) that an assumption is true, you should not make that assumption. You need to back off and justify the assumption, or else find an alternate approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each clock individually alternates between $p$ hours in an acute state followed by $p$ hours in an obtuse state, where $p=\frac{6}{11}$. If the offset between them is $x=0$ hours, then they are perfectly in-sync, and so both clocks are acute with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. If the offset between them is $x=p$ hours, then they are perfectly out-of-sync, and so both clocks are acute with probability $0$.

Clearly, as we vary $x$ from $0$ to $p$, the probability shifts linearly, and so in the range $x\in\left[0, p\right]$, the probability must be $\frac{p-x}{2p}$.

As we vary $x$ from $p$ to $2p$, the probability must linearly go back down to zero, and then this pattern must recur with period $2p$, forming a triangular wave pattern. Using the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) for triangular waves, we find that the desired probability is

$$f(x) = \left|\frac{x-p}{2p} - \left\lfloor\frac{x-p}{2p} + \frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \right|$$